# Does the Spell Sniper feat affect the size of a spell's area of effect?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats, area-of-effect

Would the Spell Sniper feat affect the width of the *lightning bolt* spell, which is normally 100 feet long and 5 feet wide? Would it also increase the explosion range of *fireball* and such spells?

Answer (score 8):

Spell Sniper doubles the range of spells, not the area of the spell's effect. In addition, Spell Sniper only doubles the range of spells that require an attack roll.

> When you cast a spell that requires you to make an attack roll, the spell’s ***range*** is doubled.

In the case of your two examples, Lightning Bolt and Fireball, neither of these spells require an attack roll, they require a saving throw. As such their range is unaffected by the Spell Sniper feat.

Answer (score 7):

## No, it doesn't; it only doubles the range (not area) of spells that require attack rolls.

The first benefit of the Spell Sniper feat (PHB, p. 170) says:

> When you cast a spell that requires you to make an attack roll, the spell’s range is doubled.

In general, area-of-effect spells require saving throws, not attack rolls.

Even if they did, though, the feat doesn't affect anything in the spell description itself - only the number in the range field.

For instance, consider the [*fire bolt*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fire-bolt) spell (PHB, p. 242):

> **Range:** 120 feet
>
> [...]
>
> You hurl a mote of fire at a creature or object within range. Make a ranged spell attack against the target.

If you have the Spell Sniper feat, and you cast *fire bolt*, it has a range of 240 feet for you, rather than 120 feet.

However, [*lightning bolt*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/lightning-bolt) (PHB, p. 255) says

> **Range:** Self (100-foot line)
>
> [...]
>
> A stroke of lightning forming a line 100 feet long and 5 feet wide blasts out from you in a direction you choose. Each creature in the line must make a Dexterity saving throw.

It is not an attack. Also, the area of effect is stated in the description; even if the range were changed (though a range of "Self" can't really be doubled), the dimensions of the area of effect ("100 feet long and 5 feet wide") in the description are unchanged.

The same is true of [*fireball*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fireball) (PHB, p. 241):

> **Range:** 150 feet
>
> [...]
>
> A bright streak flashes from your pointing finger to a point you choose within range and then blossoms with a low roar into an explosion of flame. Each creature in a 20-foot-radius sphere centered on that point must make a Dexterity saving throw.

Again, it's not an attack, so Spell Sniper doesn't benefit it. If it were, doubling the range would make it possible to center the *fireball* up to 300 feet away from the caster - but the actual area of effect ("a 20-foot-radius sphere centered on that point") would still be unchanged.

## Contrast this with the Distant Spell metamagic option

The sorcerer's Distant Spell [metamagic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/sorcerer#Metamagic) option works similarly to the Spell Sniper feat, but it doesn't have the "attack" restriction and benefits "Self"-range spells:

> When you cast a spell that has a range of 5 feet or greater, you can spend 1 sorcery point to double the range of the spell.
>
> When you cast a spell that has a range of touch, you can spend 1 sorcery point to make the range of the spell 30 feet.

However, note that it still doesn't affect the size of the area of effect - only the range of the its point of origin.